# 修飾 and ending sentences in nouns

Tags: grammar, reading-comprehension, style

Reference: This [article](http://www.manila-shimbun.com/category/society/news252340.html) ("セブ市は引き続きＥＣＱか。首都圏が再びＭＥＣＱになる可能性も") is written by 岡田薫さん from マニラ新聞:

> ドゥケ保健相は８日朝、セブ市について、**現在の防疫区分が切れる**16日以降も防疫強化地域（ＥＣＱ）に留めるとの意向を明らかにした。一方、アニョ内務自治相は８日、首都圏が修正防疫強化措置（ＭＥＣＱ）に逆戻りする可能性にも触れた。

What part of the sentence does 現在の防疫区分が切れる modify? Is it 16日 or is it 16日以降?

> ８日付セブ・デイリーニュース（電子版）によると、ドゥケ保健相はドゥテルテ大統領も出席した新型感染症省庁間タスクフォース（ＩＡＴＦ）の会議で、セブ市の現状について**発言。**「コロナ患者の増加で、病院機能がひっ迫している」と指摘した上で「住民の公衆上のリスクも高いことから、引き続き防疫強化地域（ＥＣＱ）に留める」と述べた。
>
> 保健省の中部ビサヤ地域本部は、同地域の新型コロナウイルス新規感染者数は８日午後５時現在で３１０人（７日は３５０人）と、連日３００人超えだったことを発表。うち、セブ市の新規感染者は63人（７日は１４６人）で、新たに死亡したのは７人（同３人）。セブ州では２人が死亡している。
>
> 同地域の感染者数（累計）は１万１１５５人となり、セブ市が７０７８人と全体の６割以上を占める。マンダウエ市は１１４７人、ラプラプ市は１０６４人、３市を除いたセブ州は１７６３人。同地域の死者は４１９人で、回復者は３７８１人だった。
>
> ドゥテルテ大統領から６月後半にビサヤ地域のコロナ対策責任者に任命されたシマツ環境相は７日、「私は事態を楽観的に見ている。16日からセブ市は一般防疫地域（ＧＣＱ）になると自信を持っている」と**発言**していた。

I find the sentences containing the first instance of 発言 unusual because there's no copula or verb at the end of the sentence (in contrast to the second 発言). Is this common even in online news articles where there is not much incentive to save space?

Comment: The second instance is actually 発表, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks! I overlooked it. Let me edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What part of the sentence does 現在の防疫区分が切れる modify? Is it 16日 or is it 16日以降?

切れる ("to expire" in this context) refers to an instant state change, so it modifies only 16日.

> Is this common even in online news articles where there is not much incentive to save space?

Omission of した is "news(paper) style" and it can sometimes happen even in body text.

Comment: Short and sweet. Thanks @naruto